# Question moved, tag lost

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions, tag-creation

If someone else moved a question from one SX site to another but our tag, which is quite new, has been lost for that question.

For example, someone [asked a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353029/linux-bridge-blocks-udp-packet-from-tap-interfaces?noredirect=1) about [Contiki OS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/contiki/info), since that is where they have found the tag, though the moderators moved it over to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site which is quite appropriate. But the question lost it's tag. Should the moderator take care of this specifically? I suppose that 'contiki' tag should be added on the site where the question was moved to and the moderator haven't paid attention to the context.

Comment: Simply flag the post for moderator attention to reqquest adding the tag, provided you don't have enough reputation to add it yourself, of course.

Comment: Martin, I think that was the answer and not a comment... OR was my question so obvious? :)

Comment: Well, you are also asking for a discussion: "should the mods have taken care of this when migrating?", to which I don't really have an opinion.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the target site (Unix & Linux) does not yet have a `contiki` tag, so on migration the tag was lost automatically.

If you do not have enough [reputation to create new tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags), you could instead flag the post for moderator attention (choose 'Other'), and request that the tag be created and added to the post.

Migration is an automated process, and although the mods on the source site often check with the mods on the target site if the post is going to be a good fit with the target site, it's the source site moderators that initiate the migration (I believe). They won't know if it's *appropriate* for any missing tags to be created on the target site. Thus, it's best to ask on the target site explicitly if you really want that tag to be present.

Note that because the tag wasn't present at all, noone would have been watching it either, so the fact that it's missing does not mean you lost out on attention for your question.